# How do I get the standard Windows French Canadian QWERTY keyboard layout on Ubuntu/Lubuntu?

Tags: keyboard, lubuntu, keyboard-layout, language-support, input-language

In French (Canada) I see: French (Canada, Dvorak), French (Canada, legacy), Canadian Multilingual, Canadian Multilingual (1st part), Canadian Multilingual (2nd part), Inuktitut and English (Canada) but none of them are what I'm looking for. I'm looking for the one that seems to come standard in Windows. The one where you have to "`" and then "e" to get "è" but "é" is it's own thing and you have to press "ALT+CTRL+2" to get "@" and "SHIFT+2" to get " " ". Anyway is there anyway to get this?

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: Please provide release details. for example assuming you're talking modern Lubuntu with LXQt (https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/3/3.1/3.1.1/fcitx.html?highlight=language), or a legacy Lubuntu (LXDE)... I don't use multiple languages, but to start with we need to know what system you're asking about.

Comment: I'm not aware an XKB layout which fits that specification. You may want to pick a layout which is close to what you want and create a customized variant based on it.

Comment: @guiverc: The availability of XKB keyboard layouts is unrelated to which flavor is used.